# Template class with [] operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I an using template class

```
template <class T>
class Array
{
    enum {size = 10};
    T A[size];
public:
    T& operator [] (int index)
    {
        return A[index];
    }
};
```

And all is working fine.
I want to know how the [] operator will be called from my program?

Comment: You create an instance of Array and use the [] operator on it? `Array<int> myArray; myArray[5] = 7;`

Comment: Search on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator[]` is can be called like any other method: `myArray.operator[](3) = 5`, or using the normal array syntax: `myArray[3] = 5`. When it is called this way, the value in the brackets is the function's argument.

Comment: But my question is how function call will work here?

Comment: When you write `myArray[3]` this calls the `operator[]` method on `myArray` with 3 as the argument. Don't know how else I'm supposed to explain it. It's just a normal method that can be called with a special syntax.

Comment: if i have a function "func(int n)" it is called as func(10).
But here have we passing integer inside "[ ]" operator.
Then how name mangling work for this function?

Comment: @Nagappa You can imagine the brackets simply being replaced by the normal function syntax during compilation before anything else happens. I don't think this is what actually happens but you get the idea. `myArray[x]` -> `myArray.operator[](x)`.